# Validate if integer equals string

Tags: c#, if-statement

So im trying to simply check if my variable is entered as a string, I want the if statement to go through and not an unhandled exception...

Here's my code:

```
Console.Write("Input: ");
int i;
bool success = int.TryParse("", out i);

if (success) {
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Integer!");
} else {
    i = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Output: ", i);
}
```

So what am I doing wrong here? Every time I am entering a string, I'm not getting to the if statement, only a crash!

Comment: What is the exception you're getting?

Comment: Read the docs! `TryParse` returns true *if the number is successfully parsed*. So your `if` and `else` are the wrong way around. Plus you don't need to `Convert.ToInt32` because *you just parsed your number*.

Comment: If you get a crash, you'll also get some feedback. What's the error? Does it contain a suggested course of action?

Comment: "" is not an integer, so success will be false, which will put you into your else block.  Then, whatever you are typing is causing ToInt32() to throw an exception.

Comment: You're trying to parse a value before you've even read the input for one thing. You need something like `string line = Console.ReadLine(); if int.TryParse(line, out i)) { ... } else { ... }`

Comment: Also note that you don't need an additional `Convert.ToInt32` since `int.TryParse` has already initialized `i` with the correct value if it could be parsed.

Comment: You should read your input before trying to parse it.  Put your Console.ReadLine() on its own line and assign a variable, then you can debug what has been read.  Wrap the entire piece in a try{} catch {} block and catch any exceptions so that you can understand what's going on.  Learn to use the debugger, it should become your BFF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should do it this way

```
Console.Write("Input: ");
int i;

bool success = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out i); //Getting the input and checking it

if (!success)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Integer!");
}

else
{      
    Console.WriteLine("Output: ", i);
}
```

In your code you were getting the value in the else statement and if your input cannot be parsed to `int`, then exception throws.

Answer (score 3):

The problem in your code is that the value passed to `TryParse` has no connection to the value passed to `Convert.ToInt32`. You should read the value in, then call `TryParse` *with the same value*:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter an integer:");
var s = Console.ReadLine();
int i;
if (int.TryParse(s, out i)) {
    Console.WriteLine("You entered an integer");
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("You did not enter an integer");
}
```

If you would like to continue reading until the end-user enters a valid `int`, add a loop, like this:

```
int i;
do {
    Console.WriteLine("Enter an integer:");
    var s = Console.ReadLine();
} while (!int.TryParse(s, out i));
```